# Any ideas on how to reset my zsh terminal to default?

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, terminal.app

I need help with my zsh environment. I am just getting into customizing my terminal and I have managed to mess up my terminal. I have lost access to the whole terminal as it no longer accepts any inputs from the keyboard. I am guessing that I have messed with my $PATH. Also, I have tried to reset my terminal from using the preferences of my terminal to /bin/zsh but that did not work.

[image: Immediate Response on launching the terminal]

Comment: Have you tried deleting or renaming `/users/kingfahad/.zshrc`? You may need to show hidden files in whatever file explorer you have.

Comment: Tip of the day. Keep one terminal open while you're trying out changes in a second terminal. Lets you undo whatever you just did.

Comment: Log in as `root` through console to inspect `.zshrc` and `.profile`. Return and post more details or delete question, because there doesn't seem to be enough information to fix your problem, other than make a new user.

Comment: @Paul "Log in as `root` through console": That's not how we do things in macOS.

Comment: Please clarify your situation. (1) You have tagged your question [linux], but somebody believes that you are running macOS. Which is it? (2) You say “[the terminal] no longer accepts any inputs from the keyboard”. What does that mean? What happens if you type Enter? What happens if you type `echo foo` (and Enter)? (3) Can you run some tool that lets you manipulate (view, edit, delete and/or rename) files? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: @MarlonRichert You clearly point out what a fool I am for reading the tags!

Comment: @Paul No more a fool than who added the tags. ;)

Comment: @Scott 1) Anyone who has ever spent some time with Terminal.app on macOS will recognize the screenshot for what it is. OP has probably just clicked some tags that SO suggested, without fully knowing what they are. That happens _a lot._ 2) Terminal.app shows `[Process completed]` when the shell has exited (instead of just closing the tab/window, like some terminals do). 3) The question is entirely clear to anyone who has some experience with macOS, Terminal.app and `zsh`.

Comment: From the screenshot, it seems that line 5 in your .zshrc is trying to run `x`, so this is the first thing I would fix. Perhaps this is already sufficient to get a running system again. In case  this does not work, I would configure a new Terminal tab for using a different shell (bash, for example) and from this shell debug your zsh setup.

Comment: @DaudaFahadMGarba Did my answer help you solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

1. Open the Finder. (Click the blue smiley face in the dock.)
2. In there, go to your home folder. (In the sidebar on the left, under Favorites, press the item that has a house icon and your username.)
3. If necessary, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> (Command-Shift-Dot) to show hidden files. (Hidden files are shown as grayed out.) There might be a delay in this taking effect, so wait a moment after you press this shortcut.
4. Find your `.zshrc` file. It's one of the grayed out ones.
5. Then:

   - To reset your Zsh settings to default, delete your `.zshrc` file by clicking it once and then pressing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⌫</kbd> (Cmd-Backspace). (If you see any other `.z*` files, delete those, too.) This will put it into the trash, so you can always restore it later, if necessary.
   - To try to fix the problem without losing your config, edit your `.zshrc` file with TextEdit. Make sure you save it as plain text. To toggle between plain text and rich text in TextEdit, press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>T</kbd>. (If you see a formatting toolbar, then you're in rich text mode.)

Comment: A `rm .zshrc` would seems more straightforward.

Comment: @FrédéricLoyer But OP can't use the Terminal. This solution will probably fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Open an editor like VS code and open the entire home folder.
Find the .zshrc file and clear it or fix whatever bug is there.
Open a new terminal. Should be able to interact with your aliases.